# Detect which CSS animation just ended in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css, mobile-safari

How can you detect which CSS animation just finished in JavaScript?

The ultimate need is to re-trigger a CSS animation. Due to our HTML hierarchy, we prefer not checking the element's class but instead taking action only when a particular animation ends. If you have a method that allows re-triggering an animation without removing/adding a class, please let us know.

Otherwise... our code:

```
    page.find( '.button.letter' ).on( 'webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( 'tap_animation' );

        console.log( 'Hi: ' + this.style.webkitAnimationName );

        if ( !write_mode() ) {
            do_write( this );
        }
    });
```

**this.style.webkitAnimationName** always returns the empty string.

Are we doing something wrong?

We need the code for WebKit browsers, specifically Mobile Safari.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to loop an animation, that's already supported in CSS3. If that isn't what you want, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Not to loop an animation, just retrigger it without removing/adding a class. We trigger an animation by adding a class then some undetermined time later, we need to retrigger it. If removing/adding a class is the only method, then we need to solve the question listed here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From jQuery you can access the `originalEvent` object, and, from there, the `animationName` property:

```
$('body').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function(e){
    var animName = e.originalEvent.animationName;
    console.log(animName);
});​
```

[(Webkit-only) JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3xXaE/).

From there, simply use an `if` to check what the animation name is/was (past-tense, I suppose, given that it ended).

The above updated, to give possibly a better illustration:

```
$('div').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function(e){
    var animName = e.originalEvent.animationName;
    if (animName == 'bgAnim') {
        alert('the ' + animName + ' animation has finished');
    }
});​
```

[(Webkit-only) JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3xXaE/1/).

This demo uses the following HTML:

```
<div><span>text</span></div>​
```

And CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bgAnim {
    0%, 100% {
        color: #000;
        background-color: #f00;
    }
    50% {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #0f0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontSize {
    0%, 100% {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
    50% {
        font-size: 300%;
    }
}

div {
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-animation: bgAnim;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
}

span {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-animation: fontSize;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Comment: You're too awesome, but you and your 51.4k points already know that. :) You don't happen to know another way to re-trigger CSS animations (after some user action) without adding/removing classes do you?

Comment: Why thank you! As for restarting an animation, no; I think (though I've not really explored the subject as yet) that adding/removing/toggling classes is the only way to go, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, David. We have a related question, which we're hoping you know the answer to as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499335/bind-to-custom-css-animation-end-event-with-jquery-or-javascript. If you have a chance, we would love your thoughts!

Comment: I've had a look, and posted a potential solution. Though I'm not particularly convinced that it's either a great solution, or any better than the one you already had.

Comment: One method (if your animation lends itself to it) is to have an infinite iteration animation and toggle its animation-playstate property between paused and running. (But playstate is sort of buggy right now)

Answer (score 0):

An event listener for webkitAnimationEnd should work. Something along the lines of:

```
    $object.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
        console.log( 'End Detected' );
    }, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do you detect *which* animation ended. Multiple animations run against the same object.